# shopt -s autocd missing when inside tmux?

Tags: bash, shell, shopt

It's very strange. I have `shopt -s autocd` set within my `.bashrc` file and if I run `shopt -p` in my shell I can see that it's available (and set).

But the moment I start up a tmux shell and run `shopt -p` the autocd option is no longer shown and any attempt to just move into a directory without a `cd` command prefixing it will fail with a message saying `-bash: /Users/me/some/directory: is a directory`

Here is the output of `shopt -p` *inside* tmux...

```
shopt -u cdable_vars
shopt -s cdspell
shopt -u checkhash
shopt -s checkwinsize
shopt -s cmdhist
shopt -u compat31
shopt -s dotglob
shopt -u execfail
shopt -s expand_aliases
shopt -u extdebug
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s extquote
shopt -s failglob
shopt -s force_fignore
shopt -s gnu_errfmt
shopt -s histappend
shopt -u histreedit
shopt -u histverify
shopt -u hostcomplete
shopt -s huponexit
shopt -s interactive_comments
shopt -u lithist
shopt -s login_shell
shopt -u mailwarn
shopt -u no_empty_cmd_completion
shopt -s nocaseglob
shopt -u nocasematch
shopt -u nullglob
shopt -s progcomp
shopt -s promptvars
shopt -u restricted_shell
shopt -u shift_verbose
shopt -s sourcepath
shopt -u xpg_echo
```

Here is the output of `shopt -p` *outside* tmux...

```
shopt -s autocd
shopt -u cdable_vars
shopt -s cdspell
shopt -u checkhash
shopt -u checkjobs
shopt -s checkwinsize
shopt -s cmdhist
shopt -u compat31
shopt -u compat32
shopt -u compat40
shopt -u compat41
shopt -u compat42
shopt -s complete_fullquote
shopt -u direxpand
shopt -s dirspell
shopt -s dotglob
shopt -u execfail
shopt -s expand_aliases
shopt -u extdebug
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s extquote
shopt -u failglob
shopt -s force_fignore
shopt -u globstar
shopt -u globasciiranges
shopt -s gnu_errfmt
shopt -s histappend
shopt -u histreedit
shopt -u histverify
shopt -u hostcomplete
shopt -s huponexit
shopt -s interactive_comments
shopt -u lastpipe
shopt -u lithist
shopt -s login_shell
shopt -u mailwarn
shopt -u no_empty_cmd_completion
shopt -s nocaseglob
shopt -u nocasematch
shopt -u nullglob
shopt -s progcomp
shopt -s promptvars
shopt -u restricted_shell
shopt -u shift_verbose
shopt -s sourcepath
shopt -u xpg_echo
```

Comment: Try sticking it in bash_profile/profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tmux` creates a login shell by default for each new window/pane. This means `.bash_profile` (or possibly `.profile` or `.bash_login`, depending on the available files) is executed, not `.bashrc`. See the man page for information on the `default-shell` and `default-conmand` options.

(The name of the current shell in the error message, `-bash`, also confirms that you are in a login shell, not a regular interactive shell.)